# How to loop through nested dictionaries and return a specific key value pair using a list that contains values of one of the other keys?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists with data in them and i want to use these lists to return a value from a nested dictionary in a separate list:

```
market_id_list = ['1.200840896', '1.200840895', '1.200834959', '1.200842950', '1.200834512', '1.200814585', '1.200811421', '1.200696902', '1.200685473', '1.200585216', '1.200753100', '1.200685363', '1.200686244', '1.200585437', '1.200602366', '1.200602599', '1.200827372', '1.200826376', '1.200826156', '1.200767220', '1.200826486', '1.200827262', '1.200766560', '1.200826932', '1.200767331', '1.200826822', '1.200833816', '1.200838742', '1.200696372', '1.200733401', '1.200697247', '1.200782758', '1.200617019', '1.200234714', '1.200235718', '1.200235862', '1.200718310', '1.200691561', '1.200844058', '1.199584920']

selection_id_list = ['11383611', '11383611', '10666053', '10706771', '9950800', '8813394', '8944356', '198126', '4589333', '4701919', '198133', '2362969', '5640226', '198138', '384107', '30679', '1478217', '9686394', '4837337', '139510', '503236', '4814922', '8654501', '5637030', '46956', '14092633', '10583858', '26190088', '50046', '152564', '22018255', '4525687', '30686', '56323', '48351', '47999', '58805', '194509', '29177', '4686417']

resulted_market_books = [{'marketId': '1.200840896', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 3, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 2, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640224884, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 11383611, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 8343322, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200840895', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 3, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 2, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640409453, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 11383611, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 40151973, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200834959', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 2, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640438929, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 10666053, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 13404798, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200842950', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 2, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640720572, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 10581558, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 10706771, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200834512', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 2, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640899292, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 9950800, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 43457159, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200814585', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 3, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 2, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640332740, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 8813394, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 11285528, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200811421', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 3, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 2, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640338566, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 8944356, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 9635244, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200696902', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4641147219, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 198126, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 7029037, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200685473', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4642092654, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 4589333, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 436099, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200585216', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4643779591, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 4701919, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 3859186, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200753100', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4644020903, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 198133, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 5287019, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200685363', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4644187219, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 2362969, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 408102, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200686244', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4644339434, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 5640226, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 27785243, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200585437', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4645765491, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 198136, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 198138, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200602366', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4646751161, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 384107, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 30680, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200602599', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4646762315, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 30679, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 30689, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200827372', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640640088, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 4807207, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 1478217, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200826376', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 9, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640640032, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 9686394, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 6601778, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200826156', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640730216, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 4837337, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 180563, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200767220', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 7, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640745876, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 139510, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 6511598, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200826486', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640807053, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 12174856, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 503236, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200827262', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640871530, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 4814922, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 10365200, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200766560', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640869938, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 8654501, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 7180004, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200826932', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640874288, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 5637030, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 9028306, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200767331', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640866516, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 46956, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 3667299, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200826822', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640904586, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 14092633, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 14420034, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200833816', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4647764120, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 10583858, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 502303, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200838742', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640432002, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 26190088, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 26216581, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200696372', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 0, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640681965, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 2440424, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'REMOVED', 'removalDate': '2022-07-07T17:21:14.000Z'}, {'selectionId': 50046, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'REMOVED', 'removalDate': '2022-07-07T17:21:14.000Z'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'REMOVED', 'removalDate': '2022-07-07T17:21:14.000Z'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200733401', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640727090, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 152564, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 3782270, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200697247', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4641160022, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 9195442, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 22018255, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200782758', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640449526, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 4525687, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 41309643, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200617019', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4645156875, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 14112862, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 30686, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200718310', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4641417024, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 5348606, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 41053763, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200691561', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4641146383, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 194509, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 5287007, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200844058', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 2, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4641198897, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 29178, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 29177, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200775732', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 2, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640895396, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 8347841, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 3961, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200765773', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 2, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640941972, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 235, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 7659, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200762092', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4655426856, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 971627, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 971620, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 1055557, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200756873', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 2, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4643923433, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 35784809, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 42081305, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}]}]
```

There can be duplicate ids in the selection_id_list, the entries in the market_id list are unique. The indexes in both the market_id_list and selection_id_list correspond to the indexes of the nested dictionaries within the resulted_market_books list. I want to access the nested dictionaries called "runners" within each dictionary within resulted_market_books and return the corresponding key, value pair to the selection_id in the selection_id_list for runner['status'].

Below is the code that I have written and played around with for a few weeks (i'd plan to turn this into a list comprehension once i'd nailed the loop - but haven't been able to do so):

```
for market_book in resulted_market_books:
    for market_id in market_id_list:
        if market_book['marketId'] == market_id:
            for runner in market_book['runners']:
                for selection_id in selection_id_list:
                    if runner['selectionId'] == int(selection_id):
                        print(market_id, selection_id, runner['status'])
                        break
```

The problem with the above is that getting back multiple results for some of the market_ids and their corresponding selection_ids. As shown by the output below (i've only included a subset of the output from the above code):

```
1.200840896 11383611 LOSER
1.200840895 11383611 WINNER
1.200834959 10666053 LOSER
1.200842950 10706771 LOSER
1.200834512 9950800 WINNER
1.200814585 8813394 WINNER
1.200811421 8944356 WINNER
1.200696902 198126 WINNER
1.200696902 58805 LOSER
1.200685473 4589333 WINNER
1.200685473 436099 LOSER
1.200685473 58805 LOSER
1.200585216 4701919 WINNER
1.200585216 58805 LOSER
1.200753100 198133 WINNER
1.200753100 5287019 LOSER
1.200753100 58805 LOSER
1.200685363 2362969 LOSER
1.200685363 58805 WINNER
1.200686244 5640226 WINNER
1.200686244 58805 LOSER
1.200585437 198138 LOSER
1.200585437 58805 LOSER
1.200602366 384107 LOSER
1.200602366 58805 WINNER
1.200602599 30679 WINNER
1.200602599 58805 LOSER
1.200827372 1478217 WINNER
```

Anywhere there are multiple results for a market_id is incorrect in terms of what i want. The results for the first two market_ids are correct

```
1.200840896 11383611 LOSER
1.200840895 11383611 WINNER
```

When I use slices and run the above code for only 10 indexes per list the results that come back are actually correct, so I know I must not be breaking the loop at the correct point? Any ideas?

Comment: post expected output

Comment: For the first ten market_id results if working correctly:

`1.200840896 11383611 LOSER
1.200840895 11383611 WINNER
1.200834959 10666053 LOSER
1.200842950 10706771 LOSER
1.200834512 9950800 WINNER
1.200814585 8813394 WINNER
1.200811421 8944356 WINNER
1.200696902 198126 WINNER
1.200685473 4589333 WINNER
1.200585216 4701919 WINNER`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but the data you provided is such that for each marketid there are multiple selectionid

for example: If you filter market_id to 1.200685473

```
market_id_list = ['1.200840896', '1.200840895', '1.200834959', '1.200842950', '1.200834512', '1.200814585', '1.200811421', '1.200696902', '1.200685473', '1.200585216', '1.200753100', '1.200685363', '1.200686244', '1.200585437', '1.200602366', '1.200602599', '1.200827372', '1.200826376', '1.200826156', '1.200767220', '1.200826486', '1.200827262', '1.200766560', '1.200826932', '1.200767331', '1.200826822', '1.200833816', '1.200838742', '1.200696372', '1.200733401', '1.200697247', '1.200782758', '1.200617019', '1.200234714', '1.200235718', '1.200235862', '1.200718310', '1.200691561', '1.200844058', '1.199584920']

selection_id_list = ['11383611', '11383611', '10666053', '10706771', '9950800', '8813394', '8944356', '198126', '4589333', '4701919', '198133', '2362969', '5640226', '198138', '384107', '30679', '1478217', '9686394', '4837337', '139510', '503236', '4814922', '8654501', '5637030', '46956', '14092633', '10583858', '26190088', '50046', '152564', '22018255', '4525687', '30686', '56323', '48351', '47999', '58805', '194509', '29177', '4686417']

resulted_market_books = [{'marketId': '1.200840896', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 3, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 2, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640224884, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 11383611, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 8343322, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200840895', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 3, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 2, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640409453, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 11383611, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 40151973, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200834959', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 2, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640438929, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 10666053, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 13404798, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200842950', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 2, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640720572, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 10581558, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 10706771, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200834512', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 2, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640899292, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 9950800, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 43457159, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200814585', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 3, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 2, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640332740, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 8813394, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 11285528, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200811421', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 3, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 2, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640338566, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 8944356, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 9635244, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200696902', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4641147219, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 198126, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 7029037, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200685473', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4642092654, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 4589333, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 436099, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200585216', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4643779591, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 4701919, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 3859186, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200753100', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4644020903, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 198133, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 5287019, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200685363', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4644187219, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 2362969, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 408102, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200686244', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4644339434, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 5640226, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 27785243, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200585437', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4645765491, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 198136, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 198138, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200602366', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4646751161, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 384107, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 30680, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200602599', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4646762315, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 30679, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 30689, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200827372', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640640088, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 4807207, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 1478217, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200826376', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 9, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640640032, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 9686394, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 6601778, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200826156', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640730216, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 4837337, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 180563, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200767220', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 7, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640745876, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 139510, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 6511598, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200826486', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640807053, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 12174856, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 503236, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200827262', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640871530, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 4814922, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 10365200, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200766560', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640869938, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 8654501, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 7180004, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200826932', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640874288, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 5637030, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 9028306, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200767331', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640866516, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 46956, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 3667299, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200826822', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640904586, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 14092633, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 14420034, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200833816', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4647764120, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 10583858, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 502303, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200838742', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640432002, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 26190088, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 26216581, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200696372', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 0, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640681965, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 2440424, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'REMOVED', 'removalDate': '2022-07-07T17:21:14.000Z'}, {'selectionId': 50046, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'REMOVED', 'removalDate': '2022-07-07T17:21:14.000Z'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'REMOVED', 'removalDate': '2022-07-07T17:21:14.000Z'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200733401', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640727090, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 152564, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 3782270, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200697247', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4641160022, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 9195442, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 22018255, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200782758', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640449526, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 4525687, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 41309643, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200617019', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4645156875, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 14112862, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 30686, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200718310', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4641417024, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 5348606, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 41053763, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200691561', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4641146383, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 194509, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 5287007, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 58805, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200844058', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 2, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4641198897, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 29178, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 29177, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200775732', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 2, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640895396, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 8347841, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 3961, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200765773', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 2, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4640941972, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 235, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 7659, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200762092', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 3, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4655426856, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 971627, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}, {'selectionId': 971620, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 1055557, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}]}, {'marketId': '1.200756873', 'isMarketDataDelayed': False, 'status': 'CLOSED', 'betDelay': 5, 'bspReconciled': False, 'complete': True, 'inplay': False, 'numberOfWinners': 1, 'numberOfRunners': 2, 'numberOfActiveRunners': 0, 'totalMatched': 0.0, 'totalAvailable': 0.0, 'crossMatching': False, 'runnersVoidable': False, 'version': 4643923433, 'runners': [{'selectionId': 35784809, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'LOSER'}, {'selectionId': 42081305, 'handicap': 0.0, 'status': 'WINNER'}]}]

    for market_book in resulted_market_books:
        for market_id in market_id_list:
            if market_book['marketId'] == market_id:
            
                for runner in market_book['runners']:
                    for selection_id in selection_id_list:
                       if runner['selectionId'] == int(selection_id) and   market_id_list.index(market_id)==selection_id_list.index(selection_id):
                            print(market_id, selection_id, runner['status'])
                            break
```

For each runner you have multiple selectionid matching in our case we have 4589333,58805 which are matching "selection_id_list", hence it is returning multiple rows.

If this is not what you are expecting post the expected result for this marketid

Comment: 1.200685473 4589333 WINNER

Comment: So for a marketid if >1 records are there it should always take the first record?

Comment: the list of market_ids and selection_ids have directly equivalent indexes in their lists. for market_id index = 12 then selection_id index = 12.

Comment: I have updated the code,can you please check now

Comment: added a logic to compare indexes of both lists

Comment: Just ran it - thanks a lot for doing this - it's not quite right however as i'm still getting multiple outputs for some market_ids. See below for first 10 results:

`1.200840896 11383611 LOSER
1.200840896 11383611 WINNER
1.200834959 10666053 LOSER
1.200842950 10706771 LOSER
1.200834512 9950800 WINNER
1.200814585 8813394 WINNER
1.200811421 8944356 WINNER
1.200696902 198126 WINNER
1.200718310 58805 LOSER
1.200685473 4589333 WINNER
1.200718310 58805 LOSER`

Comment: each market_id should only return one result (runner['status']) per selection_id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246667/discussion-between-gerard-mcnally-and-xi12).

Comment: sorry my bad forgot to add  if market_book['marketId'] == market_id:
please check now